# tsc and ts-node ignoring noImplicitAny

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a NodeJS project with `@types/node`, `ts-node`, and `typescript` installed as dev dependencies, and in my tsconfig.json file I have set `"noImplicitAny": true`. In my package.json file, I have three scripts:

```
"start": "npm run build && node out/index.js",
"test": "nodemon",
"build": "rimraf ./out && tsc"
```

rimraf basically deletes a folder, in this case, the output directory.

here's my nodemon config:

```
{
  "watch": [
    "src"
  ],
  "ext": ".ts,.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "exec": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json ./src/index.ts"
}
```

Now here's my code:

```
let text = 'hi'
console.log(text)
```

And `node test|start|run build` all run successfully. Surely, with noImplicitAny set, TypeScript shouldn't allow me to set the `text` variable without specifying it as `string`?

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, I'm very new to typescript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define and initialize a variable at the same time, TypeScript implicitly assigns the type from type of the initialized value, so it's not an implicit `any`, it's an implicit `string`, since `'hi'` is a `string` and only a `string`.

These two statements are identical to TypeScript:

```
let text: string = 'hi';
let text = 'hi';
```

In fact, some linters will have rules like [no-unnecessary-type-assertion](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-type-assertion.md) that prevent you from adding a type assertion that doesn't change the type.

An example of an implicit `any` is something like this:

```
const func = (test) => alert(test);
--------------^^^^ implicit any type
```